# What is the real purpose of the parameter $option_group in the function register_setting()?

Tags: options, settings-api

We have the following [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) function from the Settings API:

```
register_setting( string $option_group, string $option_name, array $args = array() )
```

I get what the $option_name and the $args are. But I have forever struggled to understand the real purpose of the `$option_group` parameter. I still fail to see its use.

I know that it is used in both `register_setting()` and [`settings_fields()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_fields/) and that the value should match. I also understand it is some way to "group" our settings (but it has no effect on the database).

1. How does it matter which string we use for this parameter?
2. Do I really need to set this string to something original or could I just use a randomly generated string?
3. What would happen if we all just left it as an empty string? How would that affect WordPress?

I have the feeling that it doesn't matter at all which value we use for this parameter as long as we use the same value for both functions.

Would the following code make sense? Assuming that each line of code was placed in the right place, with both functions having access to the variable.

```
$random_option_group = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));

register_setting( $random_option_group, 'my_option' );

settings_fields( $random_option_group )
```

Or is the content of $option_group a string that we should be able to know and remember? And if so, what for?

Answer (score 1):

The [`$option_group`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) parameter of `register_setting` should match the `$option_group` parameter of [`settings_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_fields/), which is typically used as part of creating a [custom settings page](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/).

When you use register settings with `register_setting()`, your registered settings are added to a global variable of allowed options, where they are grouped by the `$option_group` parameter. When you submit your settings page WordPress only updates the options for `$_POST` fields that match options found in the list of allowed options for the current group. The current group is determined by a hidden field that's added by the `settings_fields()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`register_setting()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) it lists the option group keys that are allowed by default:

> Default allowed option key names include `'general'`, `'discussion'`, `'media'`, `'reading'`, `'writing'`, and `'options'`.

You are able to add new keys using [`add_allowed_options()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_allowed_options/).

As to *why*: My understanding is that this allows WordPress to "know" about your settings, and allows them to be used in the context of the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/). You can, of course, define any kind of setting name you want, but if you want to leverage the management functionality of the Settings API, you should use an allowed option group name.